# Get only latest records of each ID in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables
accounts table

```
account_id    location_id
  1              11
  1              12
  2              21
  2              22
```

Events_table

```
location_id     events_id          event_date
   11              e1               2022/03/04
   11              e3               2022/03/05
   12              e2               2022/03/10
   21              e5               2022/04/10
   21              e2               2022/04/09
```

The result I expected is to get only latest event_id for  location with respect to account

Result Expected:

```
account_id  location_id   events_id      event_date
  1              11          e3          2022/03/05
  1              12          e2          2022/03/10
  2              21          e5          2022/04/10
```

Comment: Have you tried something to solve the problem ?

Comment: Yes, i have tried. I am getting events but stuck with returning only latest date row...

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
with cte as 
  ( select *,
           row_number() over(partition by location_id order by event_date desc ) row_num
    from Events
  ) select a.account_id,
           a.location_id,
           cte.events_id,
           cte.event_date
    from accounts a 
    inner join cte on cte.location_id=a.location_id
    where cte.row_num=1;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3qhqCyjZmR7dxgcFTv9oyT/0)